# Declaring a length-constrained xsd:list in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

This should be really simple, but I keep on getting errors that I can't find my way out of.  I want to declare a list of 6 floating-point numbers in an XML document and write a schema for that.

I tried this first:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="https://nisar.jpl.nasa.gov" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xsd:simpleType name="row">
       <xsd:restriction base="xsd:list">
      <xsd:length value="6"/>
      </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
```

but I get the error:

> xmlschema.validators.exceptions.XMLSchemaParseError: unknown type 'xsd:list':

And then I tried:

```
 <xsd:simpleType name="row">
    <xsd:list itemType="xsd:decimal">
       <xsd:restriction base="xsd:list">
      <xsd:length value="6"/>
      </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:list>
  </xsd:simpleType>
```

and get the error:

> Reason: Unexpected child with tag 'xs:restriction' at position 1.

And if I omit the restriction and just do the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="https://nisar.jpl.nasa.gov" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xsd:simpleType name="row">
    <xsd:list itemType="xsd:decimal">
    </xsd:list>
  </xsd:simpleType>

... Skipping bunches of code ...

    <xsd:element name="x" type="row">
     </xsd:element>
```

I get the error:

> xmlschema.validators.exceptions.XMLSchemaParseError: unknown type 'row':

So I can't even define a list that doesn't have any length restrictions on it.  From all the examples I've looked at it seems like this should work, but I'm going around the bend here.

I've done a bit more playing and deleting the targetNamespace helped a bit.  But I still don't know how to declare a list of numbers of a given type and length.

Answer (score 2):

To get the perfect restriction, you have to take several steps:

1. Define the `simpleType` which, in your case, is a primitive:

   ```
   xsd:decimal
   ```
2. Define another `simpleType` which creates an `xsd:list` above the first `simpleType`:

   ```
   <xsd:simpleType name="singleListType">
     <xsd:list itemType="xsd:decimal" />     <!-- Here the type from 1. is inserted -->
   </xsd:simpleType>
   ```
3. Define the next `simpleType` which restricts the length of the above "singleListType" `simpleType`:

   - For a length of exactly 6 items:

     ```
     <xsd:simpleType name="listType">
       <xsd:restriction base="singleListType">
         <xsd:length value="6"/>
       </xsd:restriction>
     </xsd:simpleType>
     ```
   - Or for some broader range like 3 to 5:

     ```
     <xsd:simpleType name="listType">
       <xsd:restriction base="singleListType">
         <xsd:minLength value="3"/>
         <xsd:maxLength value="5"/>
       </xsd:restriction>
     </xsd:simpleType>
     ```
4. Finally, reference the type in an element:

   ```
   <xsd:element name="x" type="listType" />
   ```

If you have problems referencing the `simpleType`s, make sure that you defined a proper targetNamespace in your XSD.

Comment: Thank-you!  This worked like a charm.  I never would have realized that I had to define two simpleTypes.